# Rewrite to not include subquery in FROM?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

A great fellow helped me with developing the following statement. However, in mySQL - I cannot save a view with a subquery in the FROM clause. Any suggestions o nhow to rewrite this so that it can be saved into a mySQL server?

```
SELECT  t.idPatternMetadata, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.sKeywords, ',', n.n), ',', -1) color , count(*) as counts
  FROM tblPatternMetadata t CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b

    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.sKeywords) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.sKeywords, ',', '')))
group by color
```

THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a table that contains the 100 integer values, and reference that table in the query.

```
CREATE TABLE n (n INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO n (n) 
SELECT a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n
  FROM ( SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
         UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
         UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
       ) a
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
         UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
         UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
       ) b
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Then rewrite your query to reference the table in place of the inline view:

```
SELECT  t.idPatternMetadata, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.sKeywords, ',', n.n), ',', -1) AS color 
     , count(*) AS counts
  FROM tblPatternMetadata t
  JOIN n 
    ON n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.sKeywords) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.sKeywords, ',', '')))
 GROUP BY color
```